# How to redirect post to category-post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, blogs

How to redirect all urls like "example.com/post-name" to "example.com/category-name/post-name" in wordpress any plugin or htaccess code is needed

Answer (score 0):

Why not tried with google?

https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=wp+redirect+plugin&oq=wp+redirect+pl&gs_l=hp.3.0.0j0i22i30l9.103657.106968.0.108274.14.14.0.0.0.0.356.2335.4j5j2j3.14.0....0...1c.1.30.hp..5.9.954.MwQ1Say9Ifs

Anyway this helps you to achieve what you want [simple-301-redirects](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) Plugin for your wordpress site. And if you have just 2 or 3 posts then use with `.htaccess` file instead of installing this plugin. But make sure to use 301 Permanent redirect that also helps you to transfer the rank of the particular page.

**Edit:** Make sure you have enabled the `category from parmalinks`

[image]

Comment: How to make changes there in simple redirect plugin?

Comment: @user2271001 just add old URL, then New url with category. That's It. like `http://example.com/old_url.html` replace with `http://example.com/category/old_url.html`

Comment: @user2271001, Hey, Do you have you already working URL? I mean new URL?

Comment: I want all the posts redirect from   "example.com/any-post" to "example.com/category-of-that-particular-post/any-post

Comment: @user2271001, you can't determine the particular category of the post, you have to insert manually all the redirects.

Comment: I have enabled category..How to automatically redirect all posts like this.  Is there any parameter like %category% that can be used in simple redirect plugin

Comment: @user2271001 you can't redirect automatically.

Comment: Look at yoast.com site, they have done it..example http://yoast.com/wordpress-hosting/  is redirecting to http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-hosting/

Comment: this plugin helped me http://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-to-categorypermalinks/